# Debugging of a simple char driver failing on container_of when reading from device attribute

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a simple char driver which accesses a PCI card. It is registered to sysfs with the help of a new class. Now I would like to access multiple parameters (i.e. version, status, control...) of the device in a convenient way. I thought of registering multiple attributes to the device (via `device_create_file()`).
To do so I create my own device structure `foo_dev` for which I allocate memory and store all device informations in it (i.e. `struct device`). Once the attribute gets called I wanted to recover my structure by using container_of() as shown in my code (stripped of return verification for readability):

```
static const ssize_t foo_show(struct device *dev,
    struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    struct foo_dev *foo_dev = container_of(dev, struct foo_dev,
        dev);
    mutex_lock(&mutex);

    u32 data = ioread32(foo_dev->bar + 0x2020);

    mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", data);
}
```

The problem: As soon as I write to the device, the kernel aborts with a `Bad IO access at port 0x2020 (return inl(port))` coming from the `ioread32()` call. Having investigated further and printed other informations stored in `foo_dev` I see that the structure is completely empty - `container_of()` apparently does not reconstruct my original structure. For completeness here the device initialization in the probe() function:

```
...
foo_dev->dev = device_create(fooClass, NULL, foo_dev->devNbr,
    foo_dev, DEVICE_NAME);

cdev_init(&foo_dev->cdev, &foo_fops);
rv = cdev_add(&foo_dev->cdev, foo_dev->devNbr, 1);

rv = pci_enable_device(dev);
...
device_create_file(foo_dev->dev, &dev_attr_bar);
...
```

What do I probably wrong? How can I investigate further on what I actually receive as `struct dev` in foo_show()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`container_of()` does *not* work with an embedded pointer.

It works only for a structure that is directly embedded in another structure:

```
struct foo_dev {
    ...
    struct device dev;
    ...
};
```

(You then have to use `device_initialize()`.)

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't `device_create()` already call `device_initialize()`? Can't I instead store the structure behind the pointer `device_create()` returns?

Comment: No, there are other points to that `struct device`. (You cannot use `device_create()`.)

Comment: Ok, so I create an empty `struct device`, use `device_initialize()` and then fill its parameters (i.e. `class`) as done by [`device_create()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/core.c#L1574)?

Comment: I actually found an alternative which solves my problem and posted it as a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

Having a closer look at `device_create()` one can see that the initialized device actually gets a pointer on its parent structure via `dev_set_drvdata()`. Instead of using `container_of()` in the attribute routine one can then recover the foodev structure with `dev_get_drvdata()`. The routine becomes:

```
static const ssize_t foo_show(struct device *dev,
    struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    struct foo_dev *foo_dev = dev_get_drvdata(dev);
    mutex_lock(&mutex);

    u32 data = ioread32(foo_dev->bar + 0x2020);

    mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", data);
}
```